# Kali LInux with broken APT

Tags: apt, kali-linux

When attempting the command to update with APT:

```
# proxychains apt update 
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net) 
0% [Connecting to 172.17.252.21 (172.17.252.21)]<--timeout:80- 
Ign:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease 
0% [Connecting to 172.17.252.21 (172.17.252.21)]<--timeout:80- 
Err:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling Release   
Cannot initiate the connection to 172.17.252.21:80 (172.17.252.21). - connect (111: Connection refused) 
Reading package lists... Done                   
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

It is unclear as to why. I am using proxychains to point to a reverse SSH listening port on port 2222.

My distro:

```
uname -a
Linux x.x.local 5.4.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.4.8-1kali1 (2020-01-06) x86_64 > GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer, in this case, was that another user had changed the apt-proxy setting to an IP address that did not exist on the network.
Run the following commands:

```
apt-config dump | grep -i proxy
```

If anything is returned, then you have a proxy config that should be removed.

Do this:

```
vim /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

Comment out or delete the lines containing the proxy settings.

Comment: Thank you for posting a solution. This begs the question why you're using Kali with multiple users. It's a specialist distribution for pentest situations, and not a general purpose system

Comment: Customer is hosting it in their environment. They didn't refresh the box so old config files were still in place (and broken).